# Use debug assets in releseUnitTest instead of the release app assets

Tags: android, testing

I run my unit tests with robolectric. For some test I added json files in the debug assest folder and get them via: `RuntimeEnvironment.application.getResources().getAssets().open(filename);`

In the debugUnitTest I have access to the the debugAssests, but if I run my releaseUnitTest I don't.

How can I tell the releaseUnitTest to get the assets from the debug folder? Or where would you save the json files to use them in the unit tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally managed to get it working. I found the answer in this robolectric github [issue](http://ttps://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/2065). Thanks to nebiros.

- Add your fixture files to the resources folder of your test one, here: src/test/resources.
- Add test resources folder to androidTest, resources.srcDirs += ['src/test/resources'], here's an example:
  android {
  sourceSets {
      String sharedTestJavaDir = 'src/sharedTest/java'

  ```
  test {
      java.srcDirs += [sharedTestJavaDir]
  }
  androidTest {
      java.srcDirs += [sharedTestJavaDir]
      resources.srcDirs += ['src/test/resources']
  }
  ```

  }
  }
- Access fixture files from your androidTest env this way: `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than keeping your json files in diff flavour's assets folder, you can put them in the `test` assets folder, which will allow all different flavours to access the assets contents.

[image: Here is a screenshot for reference]

Try adding this to the android{} block in your build.gradle file

```
sourceSets{
    test {
        assets.srcDirs = ['src/test/assets']
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Anirudh for your answer, but I don't want my unit test json file to be part of the release app. So if I will put it there it will be shipped with the app, right?

Comment: Yes, it will be. Try putting the assets folder in the test folder, just below the main folder. Will that help ?

Comment: Can you try this by adding `test { assets.srcDirs = ['src/test/assets'] }` to your build.gradle file

Comment: where excatly? It give me "Gradle DSL method not found: test()" when I try to sync gradle.

Comment: `sourceSets{
        test {
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/test/assets']
        }
    }`

Add this to the android block in the build.gradle. Working for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118340/discussion-between-anirudh-and-tim).

Comment: Thank you for your time @Anirudh I managed to find a solution on github, see my answer.